# Python MySQL not reading from database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

Python unable to read from MySql database. Connectivity works but no results returned

```
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pwd',host='<host>', port='<port>',database='mydb')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
print("Connection success")
query = ("SELECT * from users")
cursor.execute(query)
for (row) in cursor:
    print(row)

print("Print complete")    
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

I get below result

```
Connection success
Print complete
```

If I add below line

```
rows=cursor.fetchall()
```

I get below error

```
InterfaceError: No result set to fetch from.
```

I have checked from MySql workbench and I get results from above query.

EDIT: The question is not about fetchall, even without fetchall I don't see any results.

EDIT 2: 
Few Observations:

1. If I try with incorrect password, I get Access Denied error.
2. If I try with incorrect table name (with correct password) I get
   error that table doesn't exist.
3. If I add below line before the for loop

   print(len(cursor.description))

I get below error

```
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: You have already fetched the resultset by iterating over the cursor, so `fetchall` will no longer work.

Comment: add fetchall() with the cursor instance in the for loop

Comment: @snakecharmerb -- Even without fetchall, I don't see any results.

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the right database? And that the user has the right permissions?

Comment: @snakecharmerb, yes I think so. Surprising I am not even able to get output of `SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL`

Comment: Is there a ‘users’ table in database ‘mydb’? Issue the query ‘select count(*) from users’ from MySQL and see what you get.  It looks like it’s an empty table.